# How disable all the dates before a particular date in angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-components, angular-forms

I am building a component (html, css, spec.ts, ts) in angular in which I always want endDate > startDate. I have followed this link https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview in order make multiple datepickers.

Below is my HTML for `startDate` and `endDate`:

startDate:

```
<div class="start-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

endDate:

```
<div class="end-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="2">
           <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="endDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Now below is my angular code (ts) where I am calling `validateForm` method on the page load.

```
ngOnInit() {
    ....
    this.validateForm();
}

validateForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     'startDate': ['', Validators.required],
     'endDate': ['', Validators.required],
     'unavailabilityReason': ['']
    });
}
```

**ProblemStatement:**

Now what I need to do is - if I have selected any date in `startDate` (for example 23rd Nov), then in the `endDate` datepicker all the dates before and including 23rd Nov should be disabled so that I can only select dates after 23rd Nov only. Is this possible to do in Angular?

Can we achieve that by placing `minDate` and `maxDate` somewhere in HTML or TS ?

[image]

Comment: You should drop the ngModel when you are using formcontrols, it's not recommended to have two bindings, instead utilize the form controls, also use `[min]` like provided in answer, but instead use the formControl in `min` instead of ngModel value. That is my recommendation and it should work fine :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Where should I use [min] ? I tried using in TS or HTML but it didn't work (maybe I am using in wrong way). Can you give me some pointers how to use it properly ?

Comment: use it in the template, like in answer. Don't use it in TS, it's for a different purpose (numbers)

Comment: @AJT_82 I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have edited my question. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ Following is the [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159754/discussion-between-milo-and-john) we had on chat. He(Milo) mentioned to use minDate and maxDate in TS.

Comment: @AJT_82 Edited my TS and HTML code. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using a reactive form, utilize the form controls. It's not recommended to have two bindings (`ngModel` and `formControl`). So drop the `ngModel` like I suggested in a previous question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47426879/6294072

So populate your form controls with the values of from your object `unavailability`.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
  this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    startDate: [this.unavailability.startDate],
    endDate: [this.unavailability.endDate]
  });  
}
```

if you are receiving the values at a later point you can use `patchValues`:

```
this.unavailabilityForm.setValue({
  startDate: this.unavailability.startDate;
  endDate: this.unavailability.endDate;
})
```

else you can set the values when you build the form.

Then the only thing you need to add to your second datepicker is `[min]` like the other answer mentioned. There utilize the form control value:

```
<input matInput 
       [min]="unavailabilityForm.controls.startDate.value" 
       formControlName="endDate" ...>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XDGvEVjVHkNaCyy0MWAx?p=preview)**

Comment: It worked. Going forward, I will not be using two bindings.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Yes, better not to use two bindings, that can cause unexpected issues sometimes :)

Comment: Are you still around?

Comment: Yes I am, getting ready for work :) If it's about the question you linked, css is not my strong suit :D and I have only played around with material here on SO.

Comment: Hi sir, Please help me. How can we disable previous dates for " <input type= "date"> ???

Answer (score 46):

Binding with [min] works perfect for any date

.ts file

```
//today's date
todayDate:Date = new Date();

//any date
someDate: Date = new Date(anydate);
```

.html file

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="todayDate" placeholder="Appointment date" formControlName="appointment_date"> 
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Working perfectly... Thanks

Comment: That saves me many lines of codes.  In my case I only wanted the start date to be the min date so I changed that and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, you can use the `[min]=""` date property:

```
<div class="item item-2" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="2">
   <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [min]="startDate" [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="endDate" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Whatever `startDate` is will limit the Calendar dates available for `endDate`. If you need it set before `startDate` is chosen, use another variable and set it in `consturctor()` or `ngOnInit()` of your component.

See: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation

Comment: I received following error after adding [min]="startDate".

`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'min' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-datepicker-toggle'.
1. If 'mat-datepicker-toggle' is an Angular component and it has 'min' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-datepicker-toggle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.`

Comment: Any thoughts on how can I resolve this error? I am relatively new to angular.

Comment: @john sorry put it on <mat-datepicker #picker2> element instead

Comment: thats what we did before ?

Comment: can you let me know where you want to put it again.

Comment: @john it was previously on the <mat-datepicker-toggle>. I made edit where it should go

Comment: Same error, `1. If 'mat-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'min' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-datepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>`

Comment: @john sorry I just checked the docs and it goes on the `<input matInput>` element. I made another edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159754/discussion-between-milo-and-john).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am wondering where should I put minDate in the typescript ?  The snippets of code which I am using in the TS is :


  `validateForm() {
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'startDate': ['', Validators.required],
      'endDate': ['', Validators.required]
      }, 
  }`

Answer (score 3):

Using the valueChanges of Angular reactive forms and Min feature here is a complete working solution with validation and reactive forms

you can also see the image that the publishedTo only accepts values greater than or equal to any values you set on the PublisedFrom

[image]

components.ts

```
  export class AnnouncementformComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

   Announcementform: FormGroup;
   minDate:Date;

   this.Announcementform = this._formBuilder.group({

   PublishedFrom: ['', Validators.required],
   PublishedTo: ['', Validators.required],

  });
  this.Announcementform.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
    this.minDate = new Date(res.PublishedFrom);
  });
```

component.html

```
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="PublishedFrom" placeholder="Publish FROM *"
                    formControlName="PublishedFrom">
                    <mat-label>Publish FROM *</mat-label>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="PublishedFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #PublishedFrom></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="PublishedTo" placeholder="Publish To *"
                    formControlName="PublishedTo" [min]="minDate">
                    <mat-label>Publish TO *</mat-label>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="PublishedTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #PublishedTo></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I am also writing additional code below if someone needs to start his date from a specific date or greater or equal to current date can use simple line of code below

1- create a variable in your component class name it for example startDate

```
startDate:Date;

 ngOnInit() {
//---This will set the datepicker to accept values from current date or above---//
//--- you can also customize the value to set any date you want----//
this.startDate= new Date();
}
```

then in your component.html file

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="publishdate" placeholder="Publish Date *"
                        formControlName="publishdate" [min]="startDate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="publishdate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #publishdate></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest version accept `minDate` and `maxDate` as Properties

> https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

```
<mat-calendar [minDate]="theDateYouWant"></mat-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
[min]="startDate.value"
```

and worked like expected (disabled endDate calendar previous dates from selected date in startDate Calendar)

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field >
    <input placeholder="Enter Date" matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker1"
        formControlName="voucherExpirationDate"
        [min]="minDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker    #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to explain a little bit. In this case, there are some more answers, so expose the Pros of yours.

Answer (score 0):

**first date**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
   <mat-label>1st installment date</mat-label>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="firstDate (focus)="firstDate.open()"
              placeholder="Select 1st installment date" 
              formControlName="fstInstalmentDate" readonly required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="firstDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #firstDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**2nd date**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
    <mat-label>2nd installment date</mat-label>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="secondDate" (focus)="secondDate.open()"
           placeholder="Select 2nd installment date" 
           [min]="settingForm?.get('fstInstalmentDate')?.value" 
           formControlName="scndInstalmentDate" readonly required>
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="secondDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #secondDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here `settingForm` is my `formgroup` name, Just one line change in second date no need to write anything in `.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

//today's date in your component.ts file declare varaible which stores present //date
presentDate:Date = new Date();

//and in component.html write  [min]= "presentDate" in input of type date

<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="presentDate" placeholder="Appointment date" formControlName="appointment_date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
<mat-datepicker #picker>