# How disable all the dates before a particular date in angular mat-date-picker?

Tags: angular

In my application I have 2 date columns i.e., start date and end date.
If i select the start date as 10-feb-2020 then I need to disable all the dates before 10-feb-2020 for end date. How can I Do it.

```
     <div class="d-flex">

      <div class="form-group col-md-3 pl-0">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
              <label class="textColor required">Start Date</label>
            </div>
          <div class="input-group">
              <mat-form-field class="standard" floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker16" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly required="true"
                [(ngModel)]="binningDatePicker.j1RangeLs" name="j1RangeLs" #j1RangeLs="ngModel">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker16">
                </mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker16></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div *ngIf="vehicleBinningTableForm.submitted && j1RangeLs.errors" class="color-invalid">
                <div *ngIf="j1RangeLs.errors.required">{{constants.validationMessages.required}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
          <label class="textColor required">End Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <mat-form-field class="standard " floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker17" placeholder="Choose a Date"  readonly required="true"
            [(ngModel)]="binningDatePicker.j1RangeJ1" name="j1RangeJ1" #j1RangeJ1="ngModel">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker17">
            </mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker17></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div *ngIf="vehicleBinningTableForm.submitted && j1RangeJ1.errors" class="color-invalid">
            <div *ngIf="j1RangeJ1.errors.required">{{constants.validationMessages.required}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Use `min` and `max` on date input [Read More](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

Comment: I am using NG model can i use min and max with it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a reactive form? would be much easier to explain how to do it there imho

Comment: yes! assign your `startDate` ngModel variable as max for end date input

Comment: Solved in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462222/how-disable-all-the-dates-before-a-particular-date-in-angular. Regards.

Comment: I need to completely rewrite the component which is a big task for me now as I am new to angular. Is there any other solution sir.

Comment: @SameerKhan Sorry Can input have two ng models.

Comment: @rohitsiriga See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6qdmq), if you select start date as today's date then end dates should be enable after today's date