# how can disable angular material date picker between to date

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i want to disabled selected angular material between tow date . for example user can not selected any date between                     `2021-03-02` and `2011-03-02` .

i write this code :

```
 <input matInput [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker6"/>

maxDate = new Date();
minDate =new Date().setFullYear(this.maxDate.getFullYear() - 10)
```

but it not worked .

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disalbed-date-in-datapicker?file=src/app/datepicker-date-class-example.html)

**whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ???**

Comment: I suggest you to use mat-date-range-input. In this input you can't select below min date and above max date. For more reference please refer this link. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: @AmanGojariya no man . its not solved my problem

Comment: Okay then please refer this answer. Hope It will resolve your concern. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499503/8213994

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disable all the dates before a particular date in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462222/how-disable-all-the-dates-before-a-particular-date-in-angular)

Comment: @AmanGojariya i try all of taht link but thats not worked . i upfate question and put the stackbliz code

Comment: Thanks, I will check the code and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229396/discussion-between-aman-gojariya-and-mr-programer).

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your html file with below

**your.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose Start date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [max]="unavailabilityForm.controls.startDate.value" [matDatepicker]="picker1" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose End date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [min]="unavailabilityForm.controls.endDate.value" [matDatepicker]="picker" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**your.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

/** @title Datepicker with custom date classes */
@Component({
  selector: "datepicker-date-class-example",
  templateUrl: "datepicker-date-class-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["datepicker-date-class-example.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DatepickerDateClassExample implements OnInit {
  unavailabilityForm: any;
  maxDate = new Date();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let startDateTimeStamp = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 10);
    this.unavailabilityForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [new Date(startDateTimeStamp)],
      endDate: [new Date()]
    });
  }
}
```

It will resolve your concern.

Comment: thank you bro for your vote . but still i have that problem . i can select the date between 2011 and 2020 i want can not select between to date

Comment: Ohh I am not getting the question properly  give me 5 mins I will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry @Mr-Programer your problem is not fixed it's not possible. because of we are not set the max date below current date.

Comment: You need to use two dropdown

Comment: Hello @Mr-Programer I have changes my answer. You can take two different date pickers and then your concerns is resolved

Comment: You just need to replace your html and ts file now then it will work for you